# Layout is not really responsiv

Tags: css, layout, css-grid, responsive

I am currently facing a problem. My grid items move around or the layout doesn't appear as intended when I resize the browser window or activate a different toolbar. How can I change this for a desktop page so that the layout stays the same, i.e. adapts to the browser window and not everything shifts? Especially the text and buttons. Hier meine Testseite: [test](https://eazyrogue.de/test/test.html)

I've tried all possible widths and heights. vh, vw, rem, em and various blogs and forums searched but the solution was not there. Media queries also did not lead to success.

```
CSS
```

```
* {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: calc(12px + (22 - 12) * ((100vw - 1024px) / (1920 - 1024)));
    color: #000;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.wrapper  {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1920px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
    text-align: left;
}

.loading {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.loading:hover {
    background-image: url(img/loading.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 25% auto;
    background-position: center center;
    padding-top: 5%;
}

.header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 5.25% 34.4% 29% 13.3% 5.2%;
    grid-template-columns: 58.7% 23.45% 17.85%;
    grid-template-areas:
        ".  .   ."
        ".  a   ."
        "b  a   ."
        "c  a   ."
        ".  .   .";

    background-image: url(img/test_header.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 1080px;
}

.header_a {
    grid-area: a;
}

.header_b {
    grid-area: b;
    padding: 0 3% 0 13%;
}

.header_c {
    grid-area: c;
    padding-left: 13%;
}

input[type=text], input[type=button] {
    padding: 0.5em;
    background: #000;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #fff;
}

input.button {
    width: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input.button:hover {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    color: #000;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```
HTML
```

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Demo.</title>
<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header" id="header">
        <div class="header_a"><a href="https://www.easyrogue.de/test/test.html"><div class="loading"></div></a></div>
        <div class="header_b"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing.</p></div>
        <div class="header_c"><input class="button" type="button" name="download" value="Download" onClick="window.open('https://www.eazyrogue.de/test.html', '_blank')"; /></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

<header_a> is not valid HTML
check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element for valid HTML tags or run through HTML validator.

Comment: ok thanks, fixed it but problem is still alive.